# Mouse events using Locatable selenium failing for Firefox

Tags: selenium, mouse

I am using selenium locatable to trigger mouse events.For ex for mousedown:

```
    Locatable locat = (Locatable) we;
    Mouse mouse = ((HasInputDevices) driver).getMouse();
    mouse.mouseDown(locat.getCoordinates());
```

This code works perfectly fine for Chrome, but fails for firefox at last line.Is there any other approach required for firefox driver?

Comment: Fails with error "mouseMoveTo"

Comment: What is the exact error you are seeing? Can you update the question with the full error stack trace?

Comment: I am only seeing this error:
"invocation failed with error mouseMoveTo"  same for all mouse events: mouseup,mousedown, mousemove